# Dependency among different ecs tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr, ecs-taskdefinition

I have developed a backend server using multiple microservices, using spring cloud.
I have discovery service, config service, and different other services.
Right now for testing purposes, I use docker-compose to run them in the right order. Now I have decided to deploy my application on AWS.

I thought of using running them using ECS using fargare, But I am not able to understand how can I define dependency among my tasks.

I found this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_dependson
It defines dependency among containers in the same task.

But I do not think that I can run all my services with just one task as there will be complications in assigning vCPUs, even if I use 4vCPUs and huge memory then also I am not sure how well my containers will run. and after that scaling them will be another issue. Overall having such huge vCPUs and memory will incur a lot of costs as well.

Is there any way to define dependency among ECS tasks?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation supports the [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute which allows you to control the sequence of deployment (you basically trade off speed of parallelism for ordered deployments when you need them).

Assuming your tasks are started as part of ECS services you can set the `DependsOn` to a service that needs to start first.

E.g.

```
Resources:
  WebService:
    DependsOn:
    - AppService
    Properties:
  ....
  ....
```

Out of curiosity, how did you move from Compose to CloudFormation? FYI we have been working with Docker to add capabilities into the Docker toolset to deploy directly to ECS (basically converting docker compose files into CloudFormation IaC). See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/) for more background. BTW this mechanism honors the compose dependency chain. That is, if you set one service being dependent on the other in compose, the resulting CFN template uses the `DependsOn` attribute I described above.

Comment: thanks for the answer I will check it out today itself. I was using compose on my local and wanted to use aws services for production

Comment: Cool. Let me know how it goes. Anyway, if you are early on in your journey, if you follow the post I linked above you should be able to either 1) deploy to AWS directly with `docker compose up` or 2) generate a CloudFormation template from your compose file with `docker compose convert`.